# How to copy all the paragraphs and styles within a heading to another MS Word file

Tags: c#, python, ms-word, python-docx, word-style

I am using `Python docx` library and try to copy paragraphs under a few headings in many .docx files to a single new word document.

In those original .docx files, there are some custom styles created when I copy/paste the text from website, and I also manually adjusted some styles (e.g., I adjusted the paragraph spacing).

Below is my code:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.shared import Length, Pt
import copy
document = Document("test.docx")

target = Document("target.docx")
styles = target.styles

# for s in document.styles:
#     if s.name not in target.styles:
#         styles = target.styles
#         style = target.styles.add_style(s.name, WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
#         style.base_style = styles['Normal']


def get_para_data(output_doc_name, paragraph):
    """
    Write the run to the new file and then set its font, bold, alignment, color etc. data.
    """
    output_para = output_doc_name.add_paragraph()

    output_para.style = paragraph.style

    output_para.paragraph_format.alignment = paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment
    output_para.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(paragraph.paragraph_format.space_before.pt) if  paragraph.paragraph_format.space_before else None
    output_para.paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after.pt) if  paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after else None
    output_para.paragraph_format.line_spacing_rule = paragraph.paragraph_format.line_spacing_rule
    output_para.paragraph_format.line_spacing = paragraph.paragraph_format.line_spacing
    output_para.paragraph_format.first_line_indent = paragraph.paragraph_format.first_line_indent

    for run in paragraph.runs:
        output_run = output_para.add_run(run.text)
        output_run.font.highlight_color = run.font.highlight_color
        output_run.font.shadow = run.font.shadow
        # output_run.shadow = run.shadow
        # Run's bold data
        output_run.bold = run.bold
        # Run's italic data
        output_run.italic = run.italic
        # Run's underline data
        output_run.underline = run.underline
        output_run.font.name = run.font.name
        output_run.font.size = run.font.size
        # Run's color data
        output_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb
        # Run's font data
        output_run.style.name = run.style.name
    # Paragraph's alignment data

# for s in document.styles:
#     if s.name not in target.styles:
#         styles = target.styles
#         style = target.styles.add_style(s.name, WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
#         style.base_style = styles['Normal']

for para in document.paragraphs:
    get_para_data(target, para)

target.save("target.docx")
```

I tried to manually import the styles into target.docx but the style is still not the same.

My question is: what is the correct way to copy and paste the paragraphs with some modified styles into a new document? I do not mind manually import the style because in the end I just need to create a single document.

If Python cannot do it, is there any way using C#?

The line spacing and space_before/after are also not right.

Comment: What results are you getting with this code and what results were you expecting?

Comment: @scanny  I add an image and details, let me know what is wrong here?

Comment: Make sure you understand this page in the documentation: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html. In particular, adding a new style to a document adds an "empty" style. It does not automatically load presets based on the name you give it. You have to assign the desired paragraph settings etc. to the new style one by one.